# pre-push hook is reporting that git-lfs is not in my path, but it is

Tags: windows, git, git-lfs

I have git-lfs installed for Windows. It seems to be in my path for both `Git Bash` and `PowerShell`. Here is the output from `Git Bash`

```
502618458@G13G3Q72E MINGW64 ~
$ which git-lfs
/c/Program Files/Git LFS/git-lfs

502618458@G13G3Q72E MINGW64 ~
$ git lfs version
git-lfs/1.4.4 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.7.3; git cbf91a9)
```

Yet, when I run:

```
$ git lfs install
Updated pre-push hook.
Git LFS initialized.
```

I get the following in the `pre-push` hook.

```
#!/bin/sh
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs pre-push "$@"
```

I've tried deleting the `pre-push` hook and reinstalling and I still get the same result.

I tested pushing a file that should be tracked... Used `git lfs track`, added `.gitattributes` and the tracked file, but it gets push into the regular git repo instead of git-lfs storage.

Any idea why I can't get `git lfs install` to put the right contents into the `pre-push` hook or know of any workarounds?

Comment: OK. On closer inspection of the pre-push script, it appears that it is detecting `git-lfs`. If I run `command -v git-lfs || echo WTF` I get the path to git-lfs. If I replace `git-lfs` in the above command with a type like `git-lsf` I get `WTF`.

I'm still having a problem getting things to push to the git-lfs storage instead of the git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path."` was a red herring for me. It's normal to have this statement in the `pre-push` script.

If I run `command -v git-lfs || echo WTF` I get the path to git-lfs. If I replace `git-lfs` in the above command with a typo like `git-lsf` I get `WTF`

I just didn't take enough time to understand the `pre-push` script.

My problem was that I had not enabled lfs support in my Gitlab configuration file.